# How create fake users with gem devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

## seed.rb

```
20.times do
  user = User.new
  user.email = "user@ex.ua"
  user.password = "password"
  user.password_confirmation = "password"
  user.save!
end
```

**but i have many errors**

---

When i seed data:

> rails aborted! ActionView::Template::Error: Missing host to link to!
> Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or
> set :only_path to true

How create this fake users with gem devise

Comment: this error doesn't have to do with faker, and you don't show a line number, so it's impossible to say.

Comment: @maxple i fix this error. all i need is  `user.skip_confirmation!`